# flaskext Form error

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I just installed the flaskext package on my computer and I get the following error when I import a form...

Running this...

```
from flaskext.wtf import Form
```

Generated this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nater/predwebapp/flask_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskext.wtf import Form
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskext/wtf/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    __all__ += fields.__all__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
```

Not sure where to go from here.  I thought it might have been an installation error so I tried reinstalling the package, but the result was the same.  I'm using python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Technically, you installed Flask-WTF, which contained the flaskext package. If possible,  you should use `flask.ext` instead of `flaskext`, as that is the preferred method (see [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/#extension-import-transition)). Which version of Flask-WTF did you install?

Comment: I installed version 0.5.2 of python-flaskext.wtf

Comment: The latest version of Flask-WTF is 0.8.4. I'd recommend updating to a more recent version if possible. You might be experiencing [this problem](https://bitbucket.org/danjac/flask-wtf/issue/21/flask-wtf-is-broken-with-wtforms-10), which a commenter said was a problem is 0.5 but not in 0.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the latest version , you need to update the

```
from flaskext.wtf import Form
```

to

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

Notice the dot. Flask has changed how you call the extension modules since a few versions ago in general. Please see http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WTF/

Comment: Worked perfectly.  The example I was following used the old convention.  Thanks!